# The "can't add images, but post is unclear without images" problem

Tags: discussion, images

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [concatenating translation and rotation matrix - what am I doing wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903012/concatenating-translation-and-rotation-matrix-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Hi, I hope this post wasn't downvoted (no idea why it was, because the person didn't leave a comment) for reasons of "unclear" explanation of the problem.

I did my best to explain as clearly as possible with linked screenshots, which would very clearly be visible had they been embedded. They only aren't because my reputation blocked that possibility.

Comment: I've edited to make both images visible.  Keep participating in the Community and you'll soon earn enough reputation to be able to include images in your posts.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if I was expected to re-type all my calculations to be able to attach them.

Comment: The graphs as images are quite typical.  In MathJax one uses $\LaTeX$ syntax, which has good support for matrix expressions.  While they are preferred,  MathJax comes with a bit of a learning curve, and new users are often helped out with editing by experienced users.